# Have you used Rhino Igloo?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Has anyone used [Rhino igloo](http://www.ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/09/03/Rhino-Igloo-ndash-MVC-Framework-for-Web-Forms.aspx) in a non-trivial project? I am curious if it's worth, what are its drawbacks, does it enhance testability a lot, is it easy to use. How would you compare it to a pure MVC framework (ASP.NET MVC)? Please share the experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried watching [Ayende's Hibernating Rhinos on IT](http://www.ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/12/19/Hibernating-Rhinos-7-Rhino-Igloo.aspx)?  Seems like he himself isn't all that happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't compare Rhino Igloo to ASP.NET MVC.  THe reason being is MVC removes webforms from the stack. Whereas Rhino Igloo (or Castle Igloo as well) provide MVC style separation ontop of the Webforms model.  If you are *stuck* using Webforms then Rhino Igloo provides a good platform for separation.   Other frameworks that would do this include the Patterns and Practices Web Client Software Factory which offers a Model View Presenter approach.

I've toyed with Castle Igloo and found it compact and succinct to work with.  WCSF has a lot more functionality but also a lot more baggage, as it ties closely to other stuff in the Enterprise library.  If you aren't already engaged with Entlib and still want MVC/MVP webforms definately give it a look.